# \endcsname and multiply-defined labels.

Tags: errors

I am fairly new to latex but have written a few documents using it, with no major errors. I am currently writing my dissertation and after inserting a figure I generate an error.

Here is the code causing the error:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{helix.jpg}
\caption{$\alpha$ -helix formation}
\label{fig:$\alpha$ -helix formation}
\end{figure}
```

I think mainly the $\alpha$ parts, and it seems to be due to it being included within a list of figures.

I have also just noticed it says I have multiply-define labels.

```
[5] [6] (./DissertationLayout.aux
./DissertationLayout.aux:38: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \alpha 
l.38 ...ha $ -helix formation\relax }{figure.3}{}}

? 
./DissertationLayout.aux:38: Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.38 ...ha $ -helix formation\relax }{figure.3}{}}

? 
./DissertationLayout.aux:38: Extra \endcsname.
\@newl@bel ... \bbl@tempa \csname #1@#2\endcsname 
                                                  \def \bbl@tempb {#3}\@safe...
l.38 ...ha $ -helix formation\relax }{figure.3}{}}

? 
)

LaTeX Warning: There were multiply-defined labels.
```

Comment: do not use the math stuff inside a label. USe something like `\label{fig:alpha-helix-formation}` and prevent spaces in labels

Comment: Thank you! I was mistaken in thinking the label was the thing being shown within my list of figures, I now know they are used for cross-referencing.

Comment: @CarlWright: if the problem is solved do you mind if we close this as "too localized"?